# Using RGB colour codes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am still having issues understanding how to use the RGB colour wheel and get specific non-standard colours to display.   I understand that if i want my control "goaltracker" to be the standard blue, the proper code is:

```
GoalTracker.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 255)
```

I can do the same for Yellow, green, ect ect.  But what i dont understand still is how to get the non standard colours.  Is there a table or some type of methodology to use?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by non standard?

Comment: i mean i only know the RGB codes for vbRed, vbBlue, vbGreen, vbWhite, ect.  if i want to get a nice shade of light green i have know idea how to get the rgb code.

Comment: Mix the values, for example `RGB(115, 217, 134)`. It's like mixing paint (only additive rather than subtractive). By typing the above you're saying, "Give me 115 units of red, 217 units of green and 134 units of blue!".

Comment: Excellent explanation of the concepts. Now i feel "up to speed".. Thanks mate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a table here you can use to find the RGB values of various colors.

http://gucky.uni-muenster.de/cgi-bin/rgbtab-en